# How can list be filtered using bloc pattern?

Tags: flutter

I have a search page with a text field and a clickable list to filter items. The search page is separated in three diferents widgets. How can I pass the filter beetwen filter widget, list widwet and search page?
I am using block pattern to build my app but I have no idea how to achieve this

Here is my code

```
class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SearchPage> createState() => _SearchPageState();
}

class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
              pinned: false,
              snap: false,
              floating: true,
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              expandedHeight: 120.0,
              title: const TextFormFieldCustom(),
              bottom: PreferredSize(
                preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(90),
                child: Container(
                  height: 80,
                  margin:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 4),
                  child: CategoriesListView(),
                ),
              )),
          SliverListUsers(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get by with the built-in Flutter tools in sdk. In the simplest case, it is enough to use `ValueNotifier` to store and manage your business logic and `ValueListenableBuilder` to properly rebuild the interface.

Attention, I am describing the **BLoC pattern** as briefly as possible (this has no connection with packages) - as an architectural solution!

The logic would look like this:

```dart
class Item {
  String? content;
}

class FilteredItemsNotifier extends ValueNotifier<List<Item>> {
  FilteredItemsNotifier() : super([]) {
    _init();
  }

  // todo: pass through the class constructor
  late final itemsRepository;

  Future<void> _init() async {
    value = await itemsRepository.fetchItems();
  }

  Future<void> add(item) async {
    value = [...value, item];
    await itemsRepository.saveItems(value);
  }
}
```

Now all that remains is to listen to this notification correctly in the interface:

```dart
class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SearchPage> createState() => _SearchPageState();
}

class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {
  final filteredItemsNotifier = FilteredItemsNotifier();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    filteredItemsNotifier.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ValueListenableBuilder<List<Item>>(
        valueListenable: filteredItemsNotifier,
        builder: (context, List<Item> items, widget) {

          // pass `items` to the required widgets

          return CustomScrollView(
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                pinned: false,
                snap: false,
                floating: true,
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                expandedHeight: 120.0,
                title: const TextFormFieldCustom(),
                bottom: PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(90),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 80,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 0,
                      vertical: 4,
                    ),
                    child: CategoriesListView(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SliverListUsers(),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When you call the `FilteredItemsNotifier.add` method, your state will be updated and the interface will be rebuilt.

This is the simplest case, it may also be useful to consider dependency injection via the [`provider` package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) so that you can access your dependencies in the required widgets, while still having one correct instance of the desired service.